# Other things with operators

Tags: category-theory, group-actions

There is the notion of "groups with operators" which signifies a group $G$ together with a morphism of sets $X \to \operatorname{End}(G)$.

It is easily observed that the endomorphism monoid may be formed in any category, and therefore it stands to reason that there may also be rings with operators, graphs with operators etc.

I'd like to ask whether such things are actually in use in ring theory, graph theory etc.

EDIT: As a bonus, there are also "morphisms with operators", that is to say if we have morphisms of sets $X \to \operatorname{End}(G)$ and $X \to \operatorname{End}(H)$, a morphism with operators is a morphism of groups $φ: G \to H$ which commutes with the action of $X$, ie. $φ(xg) = xφ(g)$. From this, we may form a category in the evident fashion. Is this construction being used for other things than groups?

EDIT 2: Of course, there are all sorts of group actions. My question is rather about situations where the more general concept is needed.

Comment: Personally I've never seen any real need for this as a separate concept. One can either fold this into universal algebra / model theory by introducing a bunch of unary operators into the signature, or fold this into category theory by taking a suitable functor category. More common would be to require more structure of $X$, e.g. to require it to be a monoid or group or etc.

Comment: Yes, of course group actions are ubiquitous. I also noticed that after posing the question, and have edited it in this regard. Beyond that, I'd be interested in concrete examples, even if they occur formulated in the language of functor categories or model theory.